Faced this error on PyCharm when I tried to run my project on server. Can someone help me with it?
enter image description here [btw I have already installed Django PyCharm]
Tried to run my project on web server but not working for some reason. I believe it has something to do with the directory. For some reason PyCharm can't find Django in my project.

python manage.py runserver, not django

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You ran a strange command. There is nothing like django manage.py runserver.
What we have is: python manage.py runserver or py manage.py runserver for Windows users.
